# New angular project is obfuscating global css classes by default

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular15

I created a new angular 15.2 project with material and animations, here the package.json

```
  {
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.6",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^15.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

Then in the `styles.scss` I changed the material colors and imported my custom css files as i do in all my angular project:

```
@use "@angular/material" as mat;
// Plus imports for other components in your app.
@import "assets/css/tokens.css";

@include mat.core();

//Define material palettes and themes
    
@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme-light);

[data-theme="dark"] {
  @include mat.all-component-colors($my-theme-dark);
}

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

@import "assets/css/colors.module.css"; // <---- My custom css
@import "assets/css/my.scss"; // <---- My custom scss
```

The issue is that, without changing any angular default configuration, the css classes (from the `colors.module.css` are all obfuscated (but in the html they aren't), while importing the `my.scss` retreive all the classes are in plain text/not obfuscated.

I can't understand why this is happening, It's the first time i see this problem on my projects and I'm not able to find any solution searching on google and here, something changed in the default configuration of the css/sass loader on the last version of angular? How can I restore the classic behaviour?

For example, following classes present in the `colors.module.css` :

```
.background {
  background-color: var(--md-sys-color-background) !important;
}
.background-text {
  color: var(--md-sys-color-background);
}
```

are translated in this way:

[image: Obfuscated classes]

Comment: Also, changing the type of `colors.module.css` from `css` to `scss` resolved the issue, anguar (or the sass loader, idk) It's obfuscating only css files, but i need to undestand or have some documentation reference in order to set the classic behaviour.